# JQuery Bootstrap Multiselect plugin - Set a value as selected in the multiselect dropdown

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-multiselect, jquery-ui-multiselect

I am having a multiselect dropdown using the Boostrap Multiselect plugin (http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/) as below

```
<select id="data" name="data" class="data" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="100">foo</option>
  <option value="101">bar</option>
  <option value="102">bat</option>
  <option value="103">baz</option>
</select>
```

On load of page, i will get an array of value like [101,102].
I should iterate through the array and make the values selected(check boxes corresponding to the ids should be checked).
Please help.

Comment: Checkboxes? What checkboxes?

Comment: Each item in the dropdown will have a checkbox. On selecting the item, the check box will come as checked.

Comment: Thanks you all for your answers.
Taking all your answers as guideline, i resolved the problem with the below code
    var valArr = [101,102];
    i = 0, size = valArr.length;
    for(i; i < size; i++){
      $("#data").multiselect("widget").find(":checkbox[value='"+valArr[i]+"']").attr("checked","checked");
      $("#data option[value='" + valArr[i] + "']").attr("selected", 1);
      $("#data").multiselect("refresh");
    }

Thanks once again for all your support.

Comment: Good question, I don't like the selected answer, though.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Thank you all for your answers.

Taking all of your answers as a guideline, I resolved the problem with the below code:

```
var valArr = [101,102];
i = 0, size = valArr.length;
for(i; i < size; i++){
  $("#data").multiselect("widget").find(":checkbox[value='"+valArr[i]+"']").attr("checked","checked");
  $("#data option[value='" + valArr[i] + "']").attr("selected", 1);
  $("#data").multiselect("refresh");
}
```

Thanks once again for all your support.

Comment: $("#data option[value='" + valArr[i] + "']").attr("selected", 1);     Just that part for mu purposes. Thanks guys.

Comment: multiselect() is not defined anywhere in JQuery documentation? http://api.jquery.com/?s=multiselect

Comment: Refresh didn't work for me. If you have the same problem try reload instead.

Comment: I referred your solution, this worked for me `$('#multiSelect').val(valueToBeSet).multiselect('refresh');`

Comment: @K.Shaikh thank you so much this is the only thing that has worked for me!

Answer (score 159):

```
//Do it simple

var data="1,2,3,4";

//Make an array

var dataarray=data.split(",");

// Set the value

$("#multiselectbox").val(dataarray);

// Then refresh

$("#multiselectbox").multiselect("refresh");
```

Comment: What is the #multiselectbox ?

Comment: @Tito the dropdown element.

Comment: $("#ddl_multiselect").trigger("change"); using this instead of refresh worked for me.

Comment: multiselect() is not a jQuery function: http://api.jquery.com/?s=multiselect  All I get is "multiselect is undefined."  Yatin's answer below is both simpler and actually works.

Comment: @TaponSayeem its really very helpful nice and clean code

Comment: The issue for me was that refresh doesn't work try reload instead. This may have to do with different libs or different versions.

$("#multiselectbox").multiselect("reload");

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

It's supposed to be as simple as this:

```
<select id='multipleSelect' multiple='multiple'>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('#multipleSelect').val(['1', '2']);
</script>
```

Check my Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/luthrayatin/jaLygLzo/

Comment: Yes! So elegant!

Answer (score 10):

```
var valArr = [101,102], // array of option values
    i = 0, size = valArr.length, // index and array size declared here to avoid overhead
    $options = $('#data option'); // options cached here to avoid overhead of fetching inside loop

// run the loop only for the given values
for(i; i < size; i++){
    // filter the options with the specific value and select them
    $options.filter('[value="'+valArr[i]+'"]').prop('selected', true);
}
```

[**Here is a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/gpSqc/)

Answer (score 6):

work fine for  me ,change ids according to you requirement.

```
$("#FormId select#status_id_new").val('');
 $("#FormId select#status_id_new").multiselect("refresh");
```

Comment: In my case it was much simpler: `$("#listContent").val(4001);` Thks

Answer (score 4):

that code should help:

```
var selected=[101,103];
var obj=$('#data');
for (var i in selected) {
    var val=selected[i];
    console.log(val);
   obj.find('option:[value='+val+']').attr('selected',1);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

from a php array into the multiselect...

```
$PHP_array=array();           // create array anyway you need to in PHP
array_push($PHP_array,20);    // Single ID values
array_push($PHP_array,22);

$javascript_str = json_encode($PHP_array);   // JSON ENCODE
```

// then in the JS script

```
$("#multiselectbox").val(<?php echo $javascript_str; ?>);

// Then refresh

$("#multiselectbox").multiselect("refresh");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 var valArr = ["1","2","3"];

/* Below Code Matches current object's (i.e. option) value with the array values */
 /* Returns -1 if match not found */
 $("select").multiselect("widget").find(":checkbox").each(function(){
    if(jQuery.inArray(this.value, valArr) !=-1)
            this.click();

   });
```

This selects the options whose value matches with values in array.

Answer (score 2):

The [official site](http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget) has mentioned (in "Manually check or uncheck a checkbox?" section) just to use click()

e.g.

```
$("#ddl_singleSelect")
    .multiselect("widget")
        .find(":radio[value='']").click();  // change displayed selectedText
$("#ddl_singleSelect option[value='']")
    .prop("selected", true)             // change val()
    .trigger("change");                 // fire change event


$("#ddl_multiselect").multiselect("uncheckAll");    // init by de-selecting all
$("#ddl_multiselect")
    .multiselect("widget")
        .find(     ":checkbox[value='1']"
                + ",:checkbox[value='2']"
                + ",:checkbox[value='3']"
                + ",:checkbox[value='4']"
            ).click();  // change displayed selecetdText
$("#ddl_multiselect")
    .find(     "option[value='1']"
            + ",option[value='2']"
            + ",option[value='3']"
            + ",option[value='4']"
        ).prop("selected", true);   // change val()
$("#ddl_multiselect").trigger("change");    // fire change event
```

OR by [HTML](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/preselected.htm)

```
<select name="example-presets" multiple="multiple" size="5">
    <option value="option1" selected="selected">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="option3" selected="selected">Option 3</option>
    <option value="option4" selected="selected">Option 4</option>
    <option value="option5" disabled="disabled">Option 5</option>
    <option value="option6" disabled="disabled">Option 6</option>
    <option value="option7">Option 7</option>
    <option value="option8">Option 8</option>
    <option value="option9">Option 9</option>
</select>
....
<script type="text/javascript">$("select").multiselect();</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I got a better solution from [jquery-multiselect documentation](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#getting-started).

```
var data = [101,102];

$("#data").multiSelect('deselect_all');

$("#data").multiSelect("select",data);
```

Comment: this and Basant answer below works, but behave a bit different, test them and choose which behaviour suite your UI

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#dropDownId").val(["130860","130858"]);
$("#dropDownId").selectmenu('refresh');
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my code sample.
I have comma separated numbers for multi select drop down and want to select options multiple options from comma separated values.

```
var selected_tags_arr = new Array();
var selected_tags = 1,2,4;
selected_tags_arr = selected_tags.split(",");
$('#contact_tags option').each(function (){
    var option_val = this.value;
    for (var i in selected_tags_arr) {
        if(selected_tags_arr[i] == option_val){
            $("#contact_tags option[value='" + this.value + "']").attr("selected", 1);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked from me using an array as input. First uncheck all options, then click on the chosen options using jquery

```
var dimensions = ["Dates","Campaigns","Placements"];

$(".input-dimensions").multiselect("uncheckAll");

for( var dim in dimensions) {
  $(".input-dimensions").multiselect("widget")
    .find(":checkbox[value='" + dimensions[dim] + "']").click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to make a slight change using the click event on the input element by also setting the checked prop after firing the click event.

```
$(y.Ctrl).multiselect("widget").find(":checkbox").each(function () {
    if ($.inArray(this.value, uniqueVals) != -1) {
        $(this).click();
        $(this).prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope these functions will help you.

$('#your-select').multiSelect('select', String|Array);

$('#your-select').multiSelect('deselect', String|Array);

$('#your-select').multiSelect('select_all');

$('#your-select').multiSelect('deselect_all');

$('#your-select').multiSelect('refresh');

Reference by this site
 Reference

Answer (score 0):

Selects an option by its value. Works also using an array of values.
Find complete details http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#methods

```
$('#example-select').multiselect('select', ['1', '2', '4']);
```

Answer (score -3):

You can try this:

```
$( "#data" ).val([ "100", "101" ]);
```

Comment: That is correct, but this clearly looks like you copied Yatin's answer.