# Javascript auto select multiple if value is array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

I have a javascript script that allows me to select data from drop down menus, how would I modify my script to be able to select from an array instead of just a single value?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function(){
    $("select[value]").each(function() {
        $(this).val(this.getAttribute("value"));
    });
}); 
</script>
```

In the HTML code normally I would just put the value as the data from the database, and it would auto select it. But with a multi select, I have it in the database as

```
option1,option2,option3
```

And then I turn it into an array

```
Array
(
    [0] => option1
    [1] => option2
    [2] => option3
)
```

So how would I tell my script to select each and every value in the array?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery multiselect - Set a value as selected in the multiselect dropdown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966260/jquery-multiselect-set-a-value-as-selected-in-the-multiselect-dropdown)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't search very well :(

That got it to work after a bit of tweaking

Answer (score 1):

You can just set the value to your array:

```
$('#mySelect').val(myArray)
```