# Set values in jquery multiselect dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-multiselect

I want to set the multiple `ITEMS` in `jQuery multiselect dropdown` depending on the `VALUE` of that item, which I'm getting from database, separated by "`,`".

I'm saving this fetched data in `hidden field`.

Ex.

Hidden field: `hdnLots = 64,65`
, Items for lot No.: `64 = Lot 1, 65 = Lot2`

So when I get the `hdnLot=65`, then in `jQuery Multiselect dropdown` only `Lot2` needed to be selected. **And same for 64,65. i.e. When multiple values are selected than all those values needed to seleted.**

I've tried: [JQuery multiselect - Set a value as selected in the multiselect dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966260/jquery-multiselect-set-a-value-as-selected-in-the-multiselect-dropdown)

Code I've wrote for this is:

```
if ($("#<%= btnUpdateProject.ClientId %>").css('display') == "inline-block") 
{
   debugger;
   var dataarray = document.getElementById('<%= hdnLots.ClientId %>').value.split(",");
   $("#<%= ddlNoOfLots.clientid %>").val(dataarray);
}
```

Comment: Add ` $("#<%= ddlNoOfLots.clientid %>").refresh();`

Comment: add `$("#<%= ddlNoOfLots.clientid %>").multiselect("refresh");`

Comment: $("#<%= ddlNoOfLots.clientid %>").multiselect("refresh");

Comment: @Nouphal.M : Its showing error.

Comment: @user3085495 what error?

Comment: @Dharmang : I've tried it, but its changing `size(height,width)` of multiselect and neither its working.

Comment: @Nouphal.M : `Uncaught type error: Object [object object] has no method refresh`.

Comment: Sorry but $("#<%= ddlNoOfLots.clientid %>").multiselect('refresh'); is the right syntax. Also have you checked what is the value of the `dataarray` var

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem on a demo?

Comment: @Nouphal.M : It's showing only the single data in `dataarray`. i.e. `dataarray = 65` only, even if `hdnLots=64,65`.

Comment: @Dharmang: I'll try for that, but I don't think so I can do that because I'm new to this.

Comment: You need use third party service like jsfiddle to demonstrate your code in js and html language, if you don't know already.

Comment: Try alerting document.getElementById('<%= hdnLots.ClientId %>').value and see what it holds

Comment: @Dharmang: Somehow I managed to reach upto refresh method but its still showing this error: **`Uncaught Error: Cannot call methods on multiselect prior to initialization, attempt to call method 'refresh'`** in console.

Comment: This error means that your multiselect instance is not initialized. first initialize it by calling $("#<%= ddlNoOfLots.clientid %>").multiselect(); provide any options if necessary.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I hope this will help you:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/akhyp/3155/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("select").multiselect({
   selectedText: "# of # selected"
});
var hidValue = $("#hidSelectedOptions").val();
alert(hidValue);
var selectedOptions = hidValue.split(",");
for(var i in selectedOptions) {
    var optionVal = selectedOptions[i];
    $("select").find("option[value="+optionVal+"]").prop("selected", "selected");
}
$("select").multiselect('reload');
});
```

EDIT

`refresh` has been removed from latest jQuery-MultiSelect. Using `reload` will solve the question now.

Answer (score 7):

The one thing you would need to ensure is that the values in the array are strings:

```
<select id='multipleSelect' multiple='multiple'>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('#multipleSelect').val(['1', '2']);
</script>
```

Check my Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/luthrayatin/jaLygLzo/

Comment: I'm glad I could help mate!

Answer (score 4):

```
var selectedOptions = hidValue.split(",");
typeof (selectedOptions != 'undefined' && $("#hidSelectedOptions").multiselect('select', selectedOptions));
```

Comment: .multiselect('select', selectedOptions)); this part works great for me.