# How to dynamically set jquery multiselect option's selectedText in javascript ..?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp

I have following code I want to check whether each user in table row has permission with string 'all' and set "ALL permissions's Allowed" as selectedText of there respective select list.

```
 <%!
 List permission = new ArrayList();
 Connection connection;
 PreparedStatement ps1,ps2;
 ResultSet rs1,rs2;
 String sql1,sql2;   
 // execute rs1
 %>
 <table>
  <tbody>
      <% 
         while (rs1.next()) {
          String user = rs1.getString('username');
      %>
      <tr> 
          <td class="username" width="200"><%=user%></td>
          <td class="perms" width="200">
             <%
                sql2 = "SELECT perms_name FROM perms WHERE username = ? ";
               // execute rs2              
                permission.clear();
                 while (rs2.next()) {
                    permission.add(rs2.getString("permission"));
                 }
            %>
            <select class="perms" name="perms" multiple="multiple">
                <% for(int i=0;i<permsList_folder.size();i++){%>
                    <option value="<%=permission.get(i)%>" disabled="disabled" selected="selected"><%=permission.get(i).toString().toUpperCase()%></option>
                <%}%>
            </select> 
          <td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
 <script>
      var hasAllPerms ="<%=permission.contains('all')%>";// this only handle last row results not for each row/user in table          
      $(".perms").multiselect({
            noneSelectedText: "No Permission",
            selectedText:hasAllPerms=="true"?"ALL Permissions's Allowed":"# Permissions's Allowed"
      });
 </script>
```

Comment: Take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20917049/set-values-in-jquery-multiselect-dropdown . It must me some thing similar

Comment: try this http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/select2-latest.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways you can achieve what you are trying to do.

In this case it appears you are using a jsp, so you can just set the selected value and display string server side without using any javascript.

```
<select class="perms" name="perms" multiple="multiple">
   <% for(String permissionStr : permission) {
         String selectedStr="";
         String displayValue=permissionStr.toUpperCase();
         if("all".equals(permissionStr))
         {
            displayValue="ALL Permissions's Allowed";
            selectedStr="selected='selected'";
         }
   %>
      <option value="<%=permissionStr%>" disabled="disabled" <%=selectedStr%> ><%=displayValue%></option>
   <%}%>
</select>
```

---

If you want to set it using javascript/jquery one way is to add an id to each select box such as

```
<select class="perms" name="perms" id="perms<%=user%>" multiple="multiple">
   <% for(int i=0;i<permsList_folder.size();i++){%>
      <option value="<%=permission.get(i)%>" disabled="disabled" selected="selected"><%=permission.get(i).toString().toUpperCase()%></option>
   <%}%>
</select>
```

Then iterate over each user and instead of selecting the select based on class select based on id

```
$("#perms" + user).multiselect(...);
```

---

I would also not use raw types (pre java 1.5 backwards compatibility) and set the type on your permission list and add an 's' or 'List' to the name to more clearly indicate it is a collection that contains multiple permissions.

```
<%!
List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();
%>
```