# preselected values in jquery multiselect with angularjs using ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-ui-multiselect

Jquery multiselect runs perfectly with ng-option. See below for my HTML, Directive and controller.

```
 <select multiselect multiple ng-model="sched.select"  style="width:130px;" 
 ng-options="option.name for option in availableOptions track by option.value" >


.directive('multiselect', function ($timeout) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        model: '='
    },
    transclude: true,
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller, transclude) {
        $timeout(function() {
            transclude(function (clone) {
                element.append(clone);
                $(element).multiselect();
            });
        });
    }
}
});

 .controller('CreateSubject', function ($scope, factory, $cookieStore,     
 $location, $rootScope){
 $scope.availableOptions = [
 {value: "M", name: 'Monday'},
 {value: "T", name: 'Tuesday'},
 {value: "W", name: 'Wednesday'},
 {value: "Th", name: 'Thursday'},
 {value: "F", name: 'Friday'},
 {value: "S", name: 'Saturday'}    
];
});
```

Now my problem is how to preselect values in this scenario? I already tried this solution [JQuery multiselect - Set a value as selected in the multiselect dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966260/jquery-multiselect-set-a-value-as-selected-in-the-multiselect-dropdown) but it give me an error.

```
angular.js:13236 TypeError: o[e] is not a function
at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (bootstrap-multiselect.min.js:1)
at Function.x.extend.each (jquery.min.js:4)
at x.fn.x.each (jquery.min.js:4)
at t.fn.multiselect (bootstrap-multiselect.min.js:1)
at getschedule (controller.js:152)
at Scope.$scope.getsubjectschedule (controller.js:181)
at fn (eval at <anonymous> (angular.js:14086), <anonymous>:4:347)
at expensiveCheckFn (angular.js:15076)
at callback (angular.js:24546)
at Scope.$eval (angular.js:16820)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try by initilaze in your controller and use `option.name as option.name` in your `select` tag and no need to use `track by`.

in your controller:

```
.controller('CreateSubject', function ($scope){
 $scope.availableOptions = [
     {value: "M", name: 'Monday'},
     {value: "T", name: 'Tuesday'},
     {value: "W", name: 'Wednesday'},
     {value: "Th", name: 'Thursday'},
     {value: "F", name: 'Friday'},
     {value: "S", name: 'Saturday'}    
  ];
  $scope.sched = {};
  $scope.sched.select =[$scope.availableOptions[0].name,$scope.availableOptions[1].name]
;});
```

and HTML:

```
<select multiselect multiple ng-model="sched.select"  style="width:130px;" 
         ng-options="option.name as option.name for option in availableOptions" >

    </select>
```

NB. you should use `option.value as option.name` if you want to set value as `M, T` as a selected value.

and file loading order need to follow **jquery, bootstrap(css, js), angular, bootstrap-multiselect (js, css), your script file**

it may help you.

[PLUNKER DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/RVkD9TlPIs18O1JKnYft?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but your answer won't work in jquery multiselect dropdown.

Comment: What output are you desiring?

Comment: same as your demo but using jquery multiselect dropdown. See this link for reference http://formvalidation.io/examples/bootstrap-multiselect/

Comment: updated my answer and demo. can you visit now? @shinta